# Exception while cloning environment with conda

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

After installing anaconda for python2 from Anaconda2-2.5.0-MacOSX-x86_64 and `conda update conda` so that

```
$ conda --version
conda 4.0.0
```

I was working through the [test drive](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/test-drive.html) and stumbled upon

```
$ conda create --name flowers --clone snowflakes
```

because this was failing like so:

```
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata: ....
src_prefix: '/Users/flaschbier/anaconda/envs/snowflakes'
dst_prefix: '/Users/flaschbier/anaconda/envs/flowers'
Packages: 12
Files: 0
An unexpected error has occurred, please consider sending the
following traceback to the conda GitHub issue tracker at:

    https://github.com/conda/conda/issues

Include the output of the command 'conda info' in your report.


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/flaschbier/anaconda/bin/conda", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/flaschbier/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 139, in main
    args_func(args, p)
  File "/Users/flaschbier/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 146, in args_func
    args.func(args, p)
  File "/Users/flaschbier/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_create.py", line 49, in execute
    install.install(args, parser, 'create')
  File "/Users/flaschbier/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 247, in install
    clone(args.clone, prefix, json=args.json, quiet=args.quiet, index=index)
  File "/Users/flaschbier/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 84, in clone
    quiet=quiet, index=index)
  File "/Users/flaschbier/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/misc.py", line 243, in clone_env
    sorted_dists = r.dependency_sort(dists)
  File "/Users/flaschbier/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/resolve.py", line 716, in dependency_sort
    for key, value in iteritems(must_have):
  File "/Users/flaschbier/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/compat.py", line 157, in iteritems
    return iter(getattr(d, _iteritems)())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
(bunnies)yosi:anaconda flaschbier$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong

It's a bug that was reported on the github Issue Tracker here:
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2178

This bug will be fixed soon, according with the comments.

Comment: shame on me for not researching this properly :(